# Replace a hover event of a class through a new added class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new at html and Jquery/Javascript and don't know the solution for the following problem, please can anyone help?

If the class .menu-link is hovered the subsequent function is performed . . .

```
<script>
var $content= $('li.menuDescription');
var $links=$('.menu-link').hover(function(){
   /* "this" is element being hovered*/
   var index= $links.index(this);
   $content.stop().hide().eq(index).show(); 
},function(){
   /* not sure if you want to leave current content visible if user leaves menu, if so do nothing here*/
})
</script>
```

And there is a second script which adds a new class:

```
$row.find("a").addClass("hovered");
```

Now I want to use for the first script instead of

```
('.menu-link').hover
```

only the new added class ".hovered" for the subsequent function, without that a hover event occurs. Is this possible?

Many Greetings

Comment: It looks like you're mixing PHP syntax with Javascript syntax. Javascript variables don't start with `$` but PHP does.

Comment: how is php relevant here?

Comment: @Machavity JavaScript variables can start with `$`. jQuery does that.

Comment: He is not, jQuery uses $ and it is common practice to prefix variables that reference jQuery objects with $

Comment: Why do you mean by "only the new added class ".hovered" for the subsequent function, without that a hover event occurs."?

Comment: Instead of the hover event the function shall be performend when the addClass process occurs.